# Алгоритм поиска пары

Tags: клиент-сервер, алгоритм, архитектура, сервер

Такая история: есть сервер, к нему подключаются клиенты. Клиенты делятся на два типа, условно: Мужчина, Женщина. Тип определяется на момент подключения. Когда клиент шлет сообщение о том, что он готов, необходимо найти ему пару другого пола. Плюс ко всему женщина может отказаться от такой пары, и тогда поиск продолжается для них обоих.

Как реализовать это архитектурно?

Answer (score 1):

Ну как, на сервере есть таблица пользователей, в ней есть id, e-mail (допустим), пол и состояние. Клиент может послать запрос "я готов". Тогда мы на сервере смотрим его пол и запускаем поиск по таблице пользователей для другого пола. Вот даже кто-то озаботился проблемой выбора случайного элемента из таблицы: http://habrahabr.ru/post/54176.

Дальше, если запрос был от мужчины, ставим ему состояние "ожидает ответа", а выбранной женщине - "ожидаем ответа от неё". А результат заносим в отдельную таблицу, id пользователя - кто ему был выбран (ну или просто добавляем ещё одно поле в таблицу пользователей). Если запрос был от женщины, то, видимо, всё проще - сразу выдаём ей результат и всё.

Как-то так. Возможно, ещё понадобится таблица истории, кого кому выбирали, чтобы не повторяться: два поля - id мужчины, id женщины.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Михаил. Очень интересный и грамотный вариант. Но вот пару нюансов вашего алгоритма: выборка пользователей идёт не из БД, а из списка подключенных. И как быть, если подключился клиент активного поиска, но нет клиентов, которые ожидают того, чтобы их нашли?